# How to Store a sessions first name in a mysql database when a form is submitted?

Tags: php, html, pdo

How can I pass the Session into the database when the form is submitted.  I try to make this simple for everyone to understand.  Thanks for helping me out.  I don't quite understand.

PHP-  I do have session start as well.

```
<?php

 require('Conn.php');

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO Database(Client_FN, email) VALUES( :CFN, :Email)");

$ClientFN = $_POST['Client_FN'];  <-- I want to insert $_SESSION['first_name'] into the database. - Not sure how to do this?
$ClientEmail = $_POST['email'];

$statement->execute(array(
":CFN" => "$ClientFN");
":Email" => "$ClientEmail");

 // Echo Successful attempt
    echo "<p Data added to database.</p></br></br>";

    $statement = null;
    $link = null;

      ?>
```

HTML

```
<label> Name: <input name="Client_FN" type="text" 
class="form-control" id="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['first_name']; ?>"> </label> </div> 

 <label> Name: <input name="email" type="text" 
class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label> </div>
```

Comment: assign the session array to the post array

Comment: If you want to insert the value from $_SESSION, then why are you using the value from $_POST?

Comment: If I put session there, then it wont link to the form tag name.  I could be wrong.  I am trying to understand on how the name in the html links to the php and takes the session from another database and inserts it into a column Client_FN in another database.  I do have POST values as well.  I did not place them in my code here to keep it simple.

Comment: What would be the best secure way to assign the session array to the post array ?

Comment: I found that I could use $_Session['first_name'] = $_POST['Client_FN']; but I am not sure where to place it.  I had it working once but was not able to get it to work again.  Do I need to echo session?

Comment: Figure it out, Its has to do with my multiple forms being submitted at once and nothing to do with the above issue. I will ask a new question or try to find the answer.  Wish I could delete this question.  Thanks